# Pandas resampling level I data with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My school project involves a dataframe concerning the bid/ask of security.
Each row is the latest update of the "type" of transaction.

Example:
On the first row, the best bid is 140.1 at a size of 2.0.
On the second row, the best ask is 144.5 at a size of 1.0.

As the best asks/bid changes, it gets updated in the dataframe.
My project requires me to resample this data into minute data, 4 additional columns of:
i) best bid at the given minute (highest bid)
ii) best ask at the given minute (lowest ask)
iii) worst bid at the given minute (lowest bid)
iv) worst ask at the given minute (highest ask)

If there is no "updated information", a forward fill is expected.

I've tried to do it by using np.where() across the rows but it turned out to be a mess and I seem to miss the elegant approach to this. Any advice?

```
Type  Price  Size
Datetime                               
2020-04-01 15:00:01    Bid  140.1   2.0
2020-04-01 15:00:01    Ask  144.5   1.0
2020-04-01 15:15:02    Ask  142.5   1.0
2020-04-01 15:15:03    Ask  140.1   1.0
2020-04-01 15:15:03    Bid  140.0   8.0
...                    ...    ...   ...
2020-04-15 17:59:30    Bid  152.2   4.0
2020-04-15 17:59:30    Ask  152.2   4.0
2020-04-15 18:00:01    Bid  152.1   1.0
2020-04-15 18:00:01    Ask  152.3   1.0
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the dataframe in text format, with e.g. `print(df)` ?

Comment: As you requested! @horace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using a function. It seems asking a question on S/O always gets the juices flowing.

```
def extractBidAsk(df):
    
    temp = df
    
    # Extracts out all the updates to bid and ask
    temp_bid = temp[temp['Type'] == 'Bid']
    temp_ask = temp[temp['Type'] == 'Ask']
    
    temp = temp.resample('1T').last().ffill()
    
    temp_best_bid = temp_bid.resample('1T').max().ffill()
    temp_worst_bid = temp_bid.resample('1T').min().ffill()
    
    temp['Best Bid'] = temp_best_bid['Price']
    temp['Worst Bid'] = temp_worst_bid['Price']
    temp['Average Bid Volume'] = (temp_best_bid['Size'] + temp_worst_bid['Size'])/2
    temp['Average Bid Volume'] = temp['Average Bid Volume'].astype(int)
    
    temp_best_ask = temp_ask.resample('1T').min().ffill()
    temp_worst_ask = temp_ask.resample('1T').max().ffill()
    
    temp['Best Ask'] = temp_best_ask['Price']
    temp['Worst Ask'] = temp_worst_ask['Price']
    temp['Average Ask Volume'] = (temp_best_ask['Size'] + temp_worst_ask['Size'])/2
    temp['Average Ask Volume'] = temp['Average Bid Volume'].astype(int)
    
    temp = temp.drop(['Type', 'Price', 'Size'], axis=1)
    
    return temp
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `groupby` to separate bid and ask and then [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to aggregate it by minute:

```
(df.groupby("Type")["Price"]
   .resample("1Min")
   .agg([max, min])
   .dropna())
```

on your sample data (text, ignored the image), this gives

```
                            max    min
Type Datetime                         
Ask  2020-04-01 15:00:00  144.5  144.5
     2020-04-01 15:15:00  142.5  140.1
     2020-04-15 17:59:00  152.2  152.2
     2020-04-15 18:00:00  152.3  152.3
Bid  2020-04-01 15:00:00  140.1  140.1
     2020-04-01 15:15:00  140.0  140.0
     2020-04-15 17:59:00  152.2  152.2
     2020-04-15 18:00:00  152.1  152.1
```

note that the ASK at 15:15 was the only time there was enough data to show a difference